# css file comes from server but i can't see it in ie8 dev tool(F12) css tab css files combo

Tags: file, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, stylesheet, cloudflare

Strange behavior in IE8 (XP) on the local web server and remote web server. 
Generates the same html markup. 
A problem with the styles. In the case of the local server everything is fine - the stylesheet files comes. 
In the case of the web server Fiddler shows that all stylesheet files came from the server. 
But styles of it doesn’t apply and it does not appear in the on the tab CSS -> CSS files combobox  (CSS Developer Tool (F12)). Web server uses Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

It is IE 6-9 [feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx). 
To solve this problem we assemble our css files into one file.